# phpmyadmin login returns to login screen

Tags: mysql, http, phpmyadmin

I've upgraded my server from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 intending to go on to 20.04, but the original install was i386 and support for that has been discontinued.

Now, when I try to use phpmyadmin, I get the login screen. When I enter a bad password, I get the error: mysql access denied, but when I enter the right password I just get the login screen again.

Searching for this problem only gets me solutions of the form "you've forgotten your password, how to reset your password". I'm pretty sure I got the password correct as the response is different between getting it right and getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Phpmyadmin swiched to not allowing http access, requiring to login using https. Somehow the "error message" (i.e. none) is not optimal to getting the user to understand the issue.

So: phpmyadmin (in some versions?) does this when it wants you to login in using https and not http.

Tip for phpmyadmin developers: Tell this to the user while presenting the login screen: This phpmyadmin is configured not to allow http logins as they are unsafe. Now I've sent my password across the network unsecured several times while trying and trying again, not understanding what the problem was.

I know I'm going to run into this again in a few years. Hopefully by then Google knows to find this.